# Want to replace certain words using preg_replace

Tags: php

Hi I'm trying to create a database class which runs the queries. in that I sent the where condition as a parameter to a function like, `id=$no AND name='vig'`. now I want to replace the values with mysqli_real_escape_string, like `id=mysql_real_escape_string($no)`. like this. how can I do that using preg_replace.

I got this regex when searching, but I don't know how to use it with preg_replace. `'/(["\'])([^"\']+)\1/'`

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Also keep in mind that `mysql_real_escape_string` is not bulletproof. For a start you've missed a parameter to it, but you also have to ensure that every parameter of the query is quoted after being passed through the escape, otherwise stuff like ` OR 1=1 --` can slip through. My suggestion is to bite the bullet and move over to MySQLi with parameterised statements.

Comment: i'm in mysqli, but i'm not familiar with parameterized statements, is that possible to dynamically add those parameters to the query?@Polynomial

Answer (score 2):

Please don't do that !

Use **prepared statements and parameterized queries** using [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

[How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php/21449836)

Answer (score 1):

This is the dangerest thing ever, I don't want to have written this:

```
<?php

$test="we will ' hack your db";
$test2=" ' OR SANITIZE";

$where='`$test` = \'1\' and `$test2` = \'2\'';

$where=preg_replace('/(\$[^ `]+)/e','mysql_real_escape_string($1)',$where);

echo($where);

?>
```

This is dangerous not only because of mysql_real_escape_string, but also because of preg_replace with the /e (execute) flag. It is just to see if and how it can be done.

If you have to learn anyway, **please do learn prepared statements instead**.

Comment: is it possible to send multiple values dynamically inside prepared statements?

Comment: @vignesh_ms Yes, that's the idea

Comment: @vignesh_ms `$sql="... where value=:val1 and other=:val1"` they you pass `array(':val1'=>'some value','val2'=>'Some other')`